# How to Fix Infinite API Call Even Not Scrolling When Using Paging 3 Remote Mediator in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, paging

I'm new and just learning using Jetpack Compose. I found bugs which is Infinite API Call on my Remote Mediator. I'm using Bottom Bar. Here is my code:

**Here is my Remote Mediator Class**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class TopAnimeRemoteMediator(
    private val apiService: ApiService,
    private val database: TopAnimeDatabase,
) : RemoteMediator<Int, TopAnimeResponse>() {
    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, TopAnimeResponse>
    ): MediatorResult {
        val page = when (loadType) {
            LoadType.REFRESH -> 1
            LoadType.PREPEND -> return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                val lastItem = state.lastItemOrNull()
                Log.d("RRREMOTE", lastItem?.pagination?.currentPage.toString())
                if (lastItem?.pagination?.hasNextPage == false) {
                    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                } else {
                    lastItem?.pagination?.currentPage?.plus(1)
                }
            }
        }

        return try {
            val response = apiService.getTopAnime("g", page, PAGE_SIZE_CONFIG)
            database.withTransaction {
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    database.topAnimeDao().deleteTopAnime()
                }
                database.topAnimeDao().insertTopAnime(listOf(response))
            }
            MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = !response.pagination.hasNextPage)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val PAGE_SIZE_CONFIG = 5
    }
}
```

**Here is My Repository**

```
class TopAnimeRepository(private val apiService: ApiService, private val topAnimeDatabase: TopAnimeDatabase) {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
    fun getTopAnime(): Flow<PagingData<TopAnimeResponse>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = TopAnimeRemoteMediator.PAGE_SIZE_CONFIG
            ),
            remoteMediator = TopAnimeRemoteMediator(
                apiService, topAnimeDatabase
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                topAnimeDatabase.topAnimeDao().getAllTopAnime()
            }
        ).flow
    }
}
```

**Here is My viewModel**

```
class MainViewModel(database: TopAnimeDatabase) : ViewModel() {

    private val apiService: ApiService = ApiConfig.getAnimeApiService()
    private val topAnimeRepository = TopAnimeRepository(apiService, database)

    val topAnimePager: Flow<PagingData<TopAnimeResponse>> =
        topAnimeRepository.getTopAnime().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

**Here is View**

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreenBase(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val mainViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel {
        MainViewModel(TopAnimeDatabase.getDatabase(context))
    }

    val topAnimeList = mainViewModel.topAnimePager.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    val snackBarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val errorMessage = stringResource(R.string.failed_to_retrieve_data)

    when (topAnimeList.loadState.refresh) {
        LoadState.Loading -> {
            Box(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(bottom = 16.dp), // Adjust the padding as needed
                contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        }

        is LoadState.Error -> {
            LaunchedEffect(snackBarHostState) {
                snackBarHostState.showSnackbar(
                    message = errorMessage,
                    duration = SnackbarDuration.Short,
                    withDismissAction = true,
                )
            }
            Scaffold(snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(hostState = snackBarHostState) }){ paddingValues -> modifier.padding(paddingValues) }
        }

        else -> {
            LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
                columns = StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(200.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(2.dp),
                verticalItemSpacing = 2.dp,
                content = {
                    topAnimeList.itemSnapshotList.items.forEach { topAnime ->
                        items(topAnime.data.size) { index ->
                            TopAnimeItem(topAnime.data[index])
                        }
                    }
                },
                modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**The example response from API is attached on Image**

[image: Example API response]

I want to normal behaviour like it should be. When user scroll down it will request the next page data instead of requesting over and over at the beginning even though it in idle.

Comment: do you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

increase pageSize = 40 and in your repository, and in service add order by like ("SELECT * FROM HomeFeedTable order by postId")